# how to extract RGB channels from a jpeg image in R?

Tags: r, jpeg, rgb, raster

I am trying to display each channel using “image” function on a single plot using R. I have seen another question just like this and the solution was using the biOps package in R, however I couldn't install it. Is there another way of doing that?

```
img <- readJPEG(system.file("img","Rlogo.jpg",package="jpeg"))
str(img)
# num [1:512, 1:512, 1:3] 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 ...
```

Comment: When I load `pkg:jpeg` and try to run that code I get an error. Please include a proper `library` call.

Comment: `readJPEG()` returns a three dimensional array, with the red, green, and blue layers indexed via the third index. (Once you know to look for it, you can see that in the result of `str(img)`.) Do `img[,,1]` to get the red layer, `img[,,2]` to get the blue, etc. `image()` will plot that rotated 90 degrees counterclockwise. If you want to plot it upright, do, e.g. `a <- img[,,1]; image(t(a[nrow(a):1L,]))`.

Answer (score 1):

After installing the `EBImage` package from Bioconductor, try this:

```
image <- readImage('~/path/to/image.jpg')

display(image, method = 'raster')
```

This will display the original color image.

```
colorMode(image) <- Grayscale
display(image, method = 'raster',all = TRUE)
```

This will display 3 images from the RGB channels.